# Не срабатывает Invoke()

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет! Идея в том что объект двигается к точке, когда доходит до нее, то засыпает на NPCStats.WaitTime - эта переменная типа float в другом классе. После того как он поспит то переходит к движению к следующей рандомной точке.

```
public class NPCMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public NPCStats NPCStats;
    private Transform FinishPoint;
    private float Distance;
    [SerializeField] private Transform NPC;
    private int NPCDecision;
    public GameObject[] Points = new GameObject[24];

    private void Start()
    {
        Points = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Point");
        //NPCDecision = Random.Range(0, 1);
        NPCDecision = 0;
        FindPoint();
        Debug.Log("Старт");
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (NPC.position != FinishPoint.position)
        {
            NPC.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(NPC.position, FinishPoint.position, Time.deltaTime * NPCStats.Speed /10);
            //Debug.Log("Должен двигаться");
        }
        if (NPC.position == FinishPoint.position)
        {
            Debug.Log("Ушел думать");
            NPCThink();
            
        }
    }

    private void FindPoint()
    {
        
        FinishPoint = Points[Random.Range(0, 24)].transform;
        Distance = Vector3.Distance(NPC.position, FinishPoint.position);
        Debug.Log($"точка - {FinishPoint.position}");
    }

    private void NPCThink()
    {
        if (NPCDecision == 1)
        {
            Debug.Log("Принял решение двигаться");
            GetPoint();
            NPCDecision = 0;

        }
        if (NPCDecision == 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Принял решение отдохнуть");
            Sleep();
            NPCDecision = 1;
        }
    }

    private void Sleep()
    {
        Invoke("NPCThink", 5f);
        Debug.Log("Отдохнул");
    }


    private void GetPoint()
    {
        FindPoint();
        if (Distance > NPCStats.Radius)
        {
            Debug.Log("Ищет другую точку");
            GetPoint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что у вас попросту не срабатывает условие NPC.position == FinishPoint.position

Comment: Через Debug.Log() понял что не выполняется метод указанный в Invoke(), но не понимаю почему

Comment: у вас `NPCThink()` работает в `FixedUpdate`  может стоит посмотреть что происходит там?